# Embedding Windows Python in Cygwin/GCC C++ program

Tags: c++, python, windows, cygwin, embedding

I am currently working on a Cygwin/GCC application written in C++. The application requires embedding of python to run plug-ins, I've successfully embedded using the Cygwin python libraries and was able to run simple python files as part of the program. However, the python files now require the use of a windows GUI framework (wxPython), and so I need to be able to embed the Windows Python environment, otherwise I cannot use the framework in the python files. In an attempt to do this, I created libpython25.a using step 2 of [these instructions](http://sebsauvage.net/python/mingw.html). I then used the library/header files of the windows installation to compile it. However, when I run it the program crashes with some strange debugger output (debug info is on, strangely enough).

```
gdb: unknown target exception 0xc0000008 at 0x77139a13
Program received signal ?, Unknown signal.
[Switching to thread 2216.0x119c]
0x77139a13 in ntdll!RtlLockMemoryZone () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll
(gdb) where
#0  0x77139a13 in ntdll!RtlLockMemoryZone () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll
#1  0x030c1c7c in ?? ()
#2  0x030c1c80 in ?? ()
#3  0x1e0d0e80 in python25!_PyTime_DoubleToTimet ()
   from /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/python25.dll
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()'
```

If anyone has done this successfully, I would greatly appreciate the help. Is embedding Windows python in a Cygwin/GCC program possible? If not what are my other options? (Right now I can only think of moving over to VC++ but this would be pretty drastic, also I do not want to use X11 for the GUI).

Comment: Mixing the unix cpython with the windows cpython stuff is a world of hurt. Welcome to it. I'm guessing that a year has gone by and it's still not possible to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you could split the system into 2 processes - the Cygwin one (Python & C++, no wxPython) and the win32 one (Python & wxPython) and communicate between them with [RPyC](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/), XML-RPC, etc.

Comment: hm... not bad. Looking at RPyC, it seems as though we would write Python code on the Cygwin side that handles the communication between the program and the separate plug-in processes. Our app is already multi-threaded, so I guess we can extend it to be multi-process. Thanks for the suggestion, seems quite complex, but it's the best idea so far. I'll need to look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a 32 bit / 64 bit mismatch.

You are running code on a 64bit machine (because there is a SysWow64 folder), but my guess is that your python25.dll is 32 bit. What is confusing is that "system32" contains 64 bit DLLs.

+I don't think debug is on, you only see the public symbols.